# Why is fgets not reading after the first line?

Tags: c, io, fgets, fseek

I have a text file, and each line of the text file contains 3 integers, like below.

```
8 168 0
10 195 0
4 71 0
16 59 0
11 102 0
...
```

Because the file is big, I wish to use fseek and fgets write a function that can return an arbitrary line in the file. Following this [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), I wrote a function that looks like this:

```
/* puts example : hello world! */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{      
  FILE* pFile;
  char mystring [10];

  pFile = fopen ("in/data_3" , "r");
  fseek(pFile, 3, SEEK_SET);
  if ( fgets (mystring , 10 , pFile) != NULL ){
    puts (mystring);
  }

  fclose (pFile);
}
```

However, the above program returns `68 0`. When I change to `fseek(pFile, 7, SEEK_SET);`, it does not return anything. When I change to `fseek(pFile, 10, SEEK_SET);`, it returns `195 0`. It seems the number of the characters in each line is not fixed, and the newline somehow cannot return more than 1 line. How can I write the function such that it returns a complete line without knowing the size of the integer (which can be 0 to thousands)?

Comment: i think you will have to read through the entire file until you reach your desired line. not really much else you can do

Comment: "When I change to `fseek(pFile, 7, SEEK_SET);`, it does not return anything." Are you sure? two newline characters should be returned.

Comment: Yes, I just run the program. It doesn't return any newline character. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Please note that the argument to fseek is bytes, not lines.  All of the results make sense when you realize it's bytes.

Comment: If you'd formatted the input file to have a constant line length you'd be able to seek to this line via `fseek(pFile, line_number * (LINE_LENGTH + END_OF_LINE_LENGTH), SEEK_SET);`

Comment: Thanks @alk. I found another answer, which said it can't be done easily with a variable line size. I'll try mmap as the post suggests.

Comment: Note that from C standard's perspective, calling `fseek` on a text stream with "a nonzero offset and [...] the offset was not returned by a previous successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file" has undefined behaviour, so your program is not strictly conforming, and assumes a platform where there is a stricter definition (POSIX, Windows?)

Comment: C and C++ tag, in almost all cases this is one tag too much. As your code seems to need only a C compiler I remove the C++ tag, if you are actually using a C++ compiler replace the C tag by the C++ one BUT NOT THE TWO OF THEM.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I write the function such that it returns a complete line without knowing the size of the integer (which can be 0 to thousands)?

Write a function that can skip `N` number of lines.

```
void skipLines(FILE* in, int N)
{
   char line[100]; // Make it as large as the length of your longest line.
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
   {
      if ( fgets(line, sizeof(line), in) == NULL )
      {
         // N is larger than the number of lines in the file.
         // Return.
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

and then use it as:

```
pFile = fopen ("in/data_3" , "r");
skipLines(pFile, 3);
if ( fgets (mystring , 10 , pFile) != NULL ){
  puts (mystring);
}
```